How to copy some files to the desired folder inside the C# project output ($TargetDir), but not the same as the original path
I need to add some images / dlls in the Bin folder, but without following the original path. The images are under /ProjectName/Resources/Grafics. If I set them as a CopyAlways, in the bin folder, it will be in ProjecName/Bin/Resources/Grafics, but I need ProjecName/Bin/Grafics
A better solution than copyalways

Solution 1: Remove Resources folder out of equation. Then it will go directly to the bin/graphics. This is how content works. It replicates the hierarchy of your project.
Solution 2: You can keep your images anywhere you want. But add them to the resource file. On Application startup, verify if the image is not in the current executing directory + your desired directory, save it from the resource file File.WriteAllBytes(..., ...) or similar. And now you can remove the "Copy" flag. You don't need to copy them on build anymore because images will be compressed in the resource file. And any other files - the same

You can do this by using "Post-build event":
To do this in "Visual Studio 2022", the following steps are required:

1- Right click on the project inside the solution and select
"Properties".
2- Select the "Event" subsection of the "Build" section and put the
necessary DOS command in the "Post-build event" area.
3- For more details about writing the commands, please search for
"Visual Studio - Post-build event" on "Stack Overflow".

There is not much difference in "Visual Studio 2012", only the "Build Event" tab is there instead of the "Event" and "Build" sub-sections.
